# VCard in PHP - sending .vcf file via email

Tags: php, email, vcf-vcard

I am trying to send .vcf file via email in my Symfony project.

Every part seems to be working fine except the part where I need to pack my .vcf file and to send it via email. I am stuck with the part where I need to download it to some local project file and then to send that file to specific email.

```
 $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $user = $userManager->findEmail($email);

    $vcard = new VCard();
    $vcard->addName($user->getFullName());
    $vcard->addCompany($user->getCompany());
    $vcard->addEmail($user->getEmail());
    $vcard->download();

    $a = file_put_contents('/var/www/project/web/uploads', $vcard);

    // Send email
    $message = $this->container->get('mail')->createTemplatedEmail(
        $user->getEmail(),
        ('Your vCard arrived!'),
        '@WebsiteTemplates/emails/vcard.html.twig',
        [
            'user' => $user,
            'vcard' => $vcard
        ]
    );

    $this->container->get('mail')->sendMessage($message, true);

    return;
```